# How can i printf ascii code using other variable?

Tags: c, string, pointers, type-conversion

I'm learning C language.

Here's my CODE

```
int main(void)
{
    char * character = "abcd";

    printf("%d \n", *character);

    int num = character;
    int * pnum = &num;

    printf("%s \n", * pnum);

    return 0;
}
```

I got result like : 97 and abcd .

I learned 97 is ascii code of 'a'.

and I want result 97 using `pnum` variable,

So i tried `printf("%d", pnum)` , `printf("%d", *pnum)` or somethings.

But I can't get 97 from `pnum` and `num` yet.

How can i get 97 using `pnum` or `num`?

Comment: `int num = *character;
    int * pnum = &num;

    printf("%d \n", * pnum);`

Comment: %s needs a pointer, so you've to use:     `printf("%s \n", pnum);` and better, you use `char * pnum;` and a cast: `*pnum = (char *) &num;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the program has undefined behavior
.
According to the C Standard(6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 6 Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. **If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>   undefined.** The result need not be in the range of values of any
>   integer type.

For example `sizeof( char * )` can be equal to 8 while `sizeof( int )` can be equal to 4. That is an object of the type `int` can be unable to store a value of a pointer.

Instead of the type `int` in this declaration

```
int num = character;
```

you should use type `intptr_t` declared in the header `<stdint.h>`

For example

```
#include <stdint.h>

//...

intptr_t num = ( intptr_t )character;
```

So now the variable `num` contains the address of the first character of the string literal `"abcd"`.

And after this declaration

```
intptr_t *pnum = &num;
```

the pointer `pnum` has the address of the variable `num`.

Now to output the first character of the string literal you have at first to dereference the pointer `pnum` that to get the value stored in the variable `num`. This value is a representation of the address of the first character of the string literal. You need to cast it to the type `char *` and again to derefercen it.

Below is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be achieved. If you will not dereference the pointer then the whole string literal will be outputted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int main(void) 
{
    char *character = "abcd";

    printf( "%d\n", *character);

    intptr_t num = ( intptr_t )character;
    intptr_t *pnum = &num;

    printf( "%s\n", ( char * )*pnum );
    printf( "%d\n", *( char * )*pnum );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
97
abcd
97
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a result using `int *pnum` variable, because it is a pointer, and it is not pointing to an `int` value of 97.

In fact, there is no place in memory of your program where an `int` value of 97 is stored; there is a place where a `char` value of 97 is stored, but you cannot point an `int` pointer to it. Of course you can always cast `pnum` back to `char*` before dereferencing, but that is the same as your first `printf`:

```
printf("%d", *((char*)pnum));
```

If you want to get 97 into an integer variable, use `num` instead of `pnum`:

```
int num = *character;
```

This converts `char` value of `'a'` to its `int` code (97 on your system). Now you can point to it, or print the result directly:

```
int *pnum = &num;
printf("%d %d\n", num, *pnum);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Now we know format specifiers：

- d        Signed decimal integer
- i        Signed decimal integer
- u        Unsigned decimal integer
- o        Unsigned octal
- x        Unsigned hexadecimal integer
- X        Unsigned hexadecimal integer (uppercase)
- f        Decimal floating point, lowercase
- F        Decimal floating point, uppercase
- e        Scientific notation (mantissa/exponent), lowercase
- E        Scientific notation (mantissa/exponent), uppercase
- c        Character
- s        String of characters
- p        Pointer address

So, Get the code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char * chrs = "abcd";
    char * pnum = chrs;
    int num = *chrs;

    printf("%c - %d - %d \n", *chrs, num, *pnum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why link a C++ reference when answering  C question? Although this might work in the very particular case still C++ and C are *different* languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer